# .htaccess to pass FULL URL into other PHP link as $_GET

Tags: .htaccess, domain

From `.htacces` file, how to pass/redirect the FULL URL to another URL as GET Variable?

Like:

```
http://www.test.com/foo/bar.asp
```

will be redirected to:

```
http://www.newsite.com/?url=http://www.test.com/foo/bar.asp
```

With **Full Url with Domain**.
I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\.asp http://www.newsite.com/?url=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But it is going out like:

```
http://www.newsite.com/?url=?%{REQUEST_URI}
```